# Meaning of a symbol in a research paper

Tags: numerical-analysis

The 2014 paper "Iteration-Free Computation of Gauss--Legendre Quadrature Nodes and Weights" by I. Bogaert (https://doi.org/10.1137/140954969) contains the following expression in Appendix A:

[image: Expression from the paper.]

What is the meaning of the "LL" here? It is not defined in the body of the paper and it's such a commonly occurring character sequence that Googling for it has proven futile.

Comment: that may be just a typo. have you tried asking the author of the paper? his contact details are in the footnote on page 1.

Comment: Maybe there was some `\LL` latex macro, but they forgot `\\`?

Comment: This is corroborated by the preprint (https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/5683230/file/5683237.pdf), which does not contain the `LL`. (I refrain from commenting on the effect of publisher copy-editing on mathematical correctness and merely remark that a general strategy for such -- and similar -- cases is to try to find a preprint and see if it the formula is clearer there: a preprint is usually updated if serious mathematical typos are found in press, but a published paper is rarely corrected unless the author takes the blame.)

Comment: Just as a confirmation, another "post-pring" I found was on ResearchGate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262672564_Iteration-Free_Computation_of_Gauss-Legendre_Quadrature_Nodes_and_Weights where the `LL` symbol does not appear.